# Why do I get a StringFormat error with this?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, string.format

With this code (sbJava is a StringBuilder):

```
String androidFindLine = string.Format("Button _{0} = (Button) findViewById(R.id.{0});\"", btnId);
sbJava.Append(androidFindLine);
sbJava.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sbJava.Append(string.Format("_{0}.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ", btnId));
```

...I get,

> System.FormatException was unhandled
>     _HResult=-2146233033
>     _message=Input string was not in a correct format...

The value of btnId is "btnbutton_up"

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the type of the `btnId` - definitely a string?

Comment: Is `String androidFindLine = string.Format("Button _{0} = (Button) findViewById(R.id.{0});\"", btnId);` being escaped properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should escape those `{` with double `{{`:

```
sbJava.Append(string.Format("_{0}.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {{ ", btnId));
```